# How to adjust screenbrightness in React Native 0.55 CLI or higher?

Tags: react-native, screen, brightness

I have a problem, how to adjust to max brightness of screen in React Native 0.55 or higher.

I already try this library https://github.com/robinpowered/react-native-screen-brightness

```
import ScreenBrightness from 'react-native-screen-brightness';

ScreenBrightness.setBrightness(0.5); // between 0 and 1
```

But i get error when compile, and when i search on problem, it's issue to compability with React Native version.

Any suggest how to adjust screen brightness in right way ?

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: I need to know how to adjust brightness without library. Have any solution?

Comment: You can implement them on the native side and then using react native bridge, expose them to js.

Comment: Any tutorial/example code ?